# OSGi Initial Provisioning Implementation

Tags: osgi, apache-felix, equinox, knopflerfish

I'm looking for an implementation of the Initial Provisioning section of the Compendium specification.

I see that Apache Felix doesn't provide one. Knopflerfish provides one with the Pro version. I see that Equinox provides one implementation but I'm wondering if I could integrate it with an OSGi application running on top of Apache Felix.

I'm also wondering why Apache Felix doesn't provide such implementation? Is there some alternative to Initial Provisioning that has been adopted by the community?

Thanks,
Mickael

Answer (score 1):

I am sure the implementation from Equinox will run fine on the Felix framework.